# Запрос в sqlalchemy подстановка значений?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Есть таблица `offers` и у неё есть поля: `agent`,`client`,`realty`,`price`.
Так вот `offers` хранит только ссылки на эти сущности в виде id (кроме `price`). 
`realty` хранит также ссылки, но структура такая:

```
flat, house, parcel
None, None , 1
1   , None , None
```

Так вот, как задать запрос, чтобы в итоге получить не id, а названия этих сущностей (имя агента, например, имя клиента, тип недвижимости). Первое, что пришло в голову это выгрузить сначала все `offers` затем добавлять в словарь данные, сделав предварительно по запросу на каждую из сущностей. Но можно ли как-то сделать это `pythonic way`?

Comment: добавьте как выглядит ваш актуальный запрос, чтобы было от чего отталкиваться.

Comment: @oren в виде чистого SQL добавить?

Comment: в вопросах, связанных с БД, всегда желательно выкладывать структуру БД и сам запрос. вы же про flask-sqlalchemy спрашиваете, значит запрос должен быть через ORM, а не SQL.